# php generate string increment like ZA to ZB

Tags: php, string, increment

I'm trying to generate strings in PHP like

> "A" next "B"..."Z" next "ZA" next "ZB"..."ZZ" next "ZZA" next "ZZB"..."ZZZ" next "ZZZA"

Could someone help me with a method?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I wrote a script back in the day that did this and it turned out to be the most efficient way, if I find it i'll post it. Have a look for a script you might find it.

Comment: @Jek interesting. Please post if you find it. Not sure how it can be done more efficient then posted below.

Comment: first link above is not the same .
second link is nearly i changed the code little bit

Comment: Well, @djramc, it was meant to follow certain criteria and it was for an old hackathon I attended. It was to build the underlying string generator for a brute force, generating every possible string as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 1):

simply use increment [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) -

```
$a = "A";
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
        echo $a++.' ';
}
```

just run this code to see the magic.

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can count in letters.

```
For($i='A'; $i<='ZZZA'; $i++){
   Echo $i ."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/VgLi8